# NOT_FOUND_ERR while trying to load Ionic file as blob from android device

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I am getting a `FileError {code: 1}` while trying to load a file from my android device using `cordova-plugin-file`. My code:

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
...

private loadGpkgBlob(): Promise<any> {
  const gpkgPath = this.file.externalRootDirectory + "test_dir/test.gpkg";

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(gpkgPath).then((fileEntry: any) => {
      fileEntry.file(gpkgFile => {
        // file is present (see screenshot 1)
        console.log("gpkgFile: ", gpkgFile);

        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
          const blob = new Blob([reader.result], { type: 'application/geopackage+sqlite3' });
          // blob with size 4 (see screenshot 2)
          console.log("result: ", blob);
          resolve(blob);
        };

        reader.onerror = function (e) {
          // FileError {code: 1} -> NOT_FOUND_ERR (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError)
          console.log("error: ", reader.error);
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(gpkgFile);
      });
    }).catch(e => e => console.log(e));
  });
}
```

**Screenshot 1 - file on the device:**

[image]

**Screenshot 2 - gpkg-blob:**

[image]

The file is obviously found. Any suggestions on how to fix/debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because of the file plugin cant resolve the path you have provide.

so basically you need to use one more plugin `FilePath` which can resolve this path and will provide you new path which can be resolved by the file plugin.

```
const nativeFilePath = await this.filepath.resolveNativePath(gpkgPath);


return this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(nativeFilePath).then((fileEntry: any) => {
```

I have mentioned this file Path plugin URL below. After this change it will work for you :)

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-path

Incase you dont want to do this with async then you can use it like mentioned below

```
this.filePath.resolveNativePath(gpkgPath)
  .then(nativeFilePath => {
      return this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(nativeFilePath).then((fileEntry: any) => {

  //// your rest code
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

please check below screenshot its working for me

[image]

Comment: filePath seems not to help: nativeFilePath is "file:///storage/emulated/0/test_dir/test.gpkg".
Geopackage localURL does not change (should it?).

Comment: filePath will help you here. i have setup everything on my local and given it a try .. earlier it was not working for me either but after this change it started working.. please give it a try

Comment: i might be wrong that about the path ,. i did go in that much deeper but it will work for you after this chaneg i can bet

Comment: on the file path plugin they have clearly mentioned that this plugin will allow you to `resolve the native filesystem path for Android`

Comment: I am still getting the same result... Is some special configuration necessary? I read about different security policies and added this to my index.html:
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://localhost:8100 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: cdvfile://* file://* content://* gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com;"/>`

Comment: Did you try file path ? I think those are not required .. i belive its just about the permission to that file not sure much

Comment: Yes I used filePath to get my nativeFilePath result (first comment): "file:///storage/emulated/0/test_dir/test.gpkg"

Comment: Yeah path is same but it might have change the permission to your file . So after this call . It will work for you

Comment: Hello mate. Actually this file path gives you permission to read file from external directory .. after kitkat version Android has updated their policy. You won't be able to access media file. So we need this plugin. You can checkout the github for this plugin they have explained why this plugin was developed for android..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226980/discussion-between-taylor-rahul-and-lars).